# getting posts and number by specific meta value in multiple meta

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

i have a multiple meta (custom field) in posts as "cd_meta"
that it (cd_meta) have a meta as "artist", also "artist" meta maybe have one or more value in array

i want to getting posts that "artist" meta have specific value and number of them

look below picture for more info
[image]

Comment: How do you store `cd_meta`? Is it a serialized array with keys `artist`, `video_type`, etc., or each key (`artist`, `video_type`) is a separate custom field?

Comment: @nmr , i think serialized and not separate. from above picture artist, video_type and .. are in cd_meta

Comment: probably, but  I was not sure that it was not processed in PHP

Comment: its serialized and must search in serialized , how do it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you store an array as `meta_value` you are storing a string with serialized data that represents the original array. This format is appropriated for data that are **only** intended to display.

Data that you plan to use for ordering or searching by or in any other way that is not just display the information should **NOT** be stored as serialized array. You should store each array key in its own meta field.

In you example you want to search post by `artist` meta field, so think about the change from array `artist[1599, 5240]` to two single value meta fields (all with "**artist**" as `meta_key`, you can store a key more than once):

> [artist]  => '1599'
>   [artist] => '5240'

---

#### Update

> it's serialized and must search in serialized, how do it ?

It is technically possible to search text with the LIKE operator and surrounding value with `"`, but it's inefficient query. You have no guarantee of the results consistent, because searched value can appear in other array key (e.g. `rev`, `master`, etc.). Storing `artist` as separate meta fields is a preferable solution.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'cp_meta',
        'value'   => '"1599"', // OR  ':"1599"'
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your SQL Query

```
$args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'cp_annonceur',
           'value' => 'professionnel',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: My Code
[link](http://uupload.ir/files/3xj_capture_37.jpg)

Comment: Please don't  post code as a picture. Edit the question and paste the code. @ebeliejinfren